# How can apply coördinate descent method on the finding least norm solution of a linear system?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear system $Ax=b$, where $A\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\Bbb R^m$. Given the possibility of multiple solutions, I want to find a least norm solution for this system by solving the problem:

$\min\{{\Vert x \Vert}_2 {}^2 $ subject to$ $ Ax=b$\}$

how can i apply coordinate descent method to this optimization problem?

Comment: First you need to handle the constraint, for instance with duality or applying a projected gradient descent

Comment: With "coordinate descent", do you mean to successively optimize the target function parallel to a coordinate axis, solving $\min_t f(x+te_k)$, $k=1,..,n$ and repeating, to find a minimizing sequence, in similarity to the Gauß-Seidel method?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes! How can i apply it?

Comment: @VanBaffo please introduce some good references, thanks!

Comment: Do you already have a solver method for the linear system? Do you know what a KKT system is? Are penalty modifications of the target function admissible?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't have any exact idea for solving it, but i think maybe we can use Lagrangian relaxation as we can use it in Kaczmarz methods. Is this idea work?

Comment: That sounds good. But do not lose the aim of this exercise, you want an almost trivial heuristic approach similar to the Gauss-Seidel method, reduce the multi-dimensional problem to a sequence of scalar problems that can be solved using intuition from elementary calculus. Otherwise the solution is given using the QR decomposition of $(A|b)$. One could try to interpret its computation via Givens rotations as such a sequential method.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I read an article which said this optimization problem with coordinate descent equals to following problem at every iteration: min||b-Ax|| s.t. x=x_k + lambda*e_i , do you have any comment about this? I can't understand. Thanks!

Comment: Please add substantial clarifications and sources directly to the question text, you have then more control on formatting and later corrections. Make sure to keep the additions in some recognizable chronological order.

Comment: That is a valid method, will however not guarantee to find the smallest $x$. Additionally the convergence can be very slow. It is the same as I wrote above for coordinate descent, with $f(x)=\|Ax-b\|$ and some different variable names.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need numerical methods, like gradient descent, to find $x$: if $|x|^2$ is minimal subject to $Ax=b$ then
the gradient of $|x|^2$ (which is $2x$) must be orthogonal to the constraint space.

But
the space orthogonal to $Ax=b$ consists of rows of $A$, which means that all orthogonal
vectors can be represented as $\tilde x = A^T u$ where $u\in \mathbb R^m$. Applying the
constraint again we get:
$$
AA^T u = b
\;\;\;\;
\Longrightarrow
\;\;\;
u =(AA^T)^{-1}b  
\;\;\;\;
\Longrightarrow
$$
$$
\tilde x = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b
$$